# How to define an inductive type mutually recursive with a function?

Tags: coq, induction, mutual-recursion

I want to define an inductive type `Foo`, with constructors accepting as arguments some properties. I want those properties to depend on inductive arguments of the type I am currently defining. I want to be able to collect some data from them inside those properties using some recursive function `bar` that would take an object of type `Foo`. However, I don't know of a way to declare those two so that Coq would accept their definitions. I want to be able to write something like this:

```
Inductive Foo : Set (* or Type *) :=
| Foo1 : forall f : Foo, bar f = 1 -> Foo
| Foo2 : forall f : Foo,  bar f = 2 -> Foo
| Foon : nat -> Foo
with bar (f : Foo) : nat := 
  match f with
  | Foo1 _ _ => 1
  | Foo2 _ _ => 2
  | Foon n => S n
  end.
```

Usually, `with` is the way to handle mutual recursion, however all examples I've seen was it being used with both definitions begin either both `Inductive` or both `Fixpoint`. Is such mutual recursion even possible?

Comment: Worst comes to worst, I think you can always "recast" the usage of a function like `bar` in terms of an `Inductive` representing its graph. That translation might be overkill for this purpose though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of definition is known as an "inductive-recursive". It is not supported in Coq, unfortunately, but it is supported in the Agda theorem prover, if I am not mistaken.